# Fill dropdownlist when there is no data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a dropdownlist that are filled with age ranging from 0-100. This the user can then choose and the selected value gets inserted into a database via linq. The user doesn't have an age value in the database but this is something that he will add later on the edit page. The problem is that there is an error when loading the "edit profile page" if there is no a NULL value on age in the database.

Error message:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DatingSite.Members.Redigera.getData(Guid user) in c:\DatingSite\DatingSite\Members\Redigera.aspx.cs:line 43
```

Code for dropdownlist:

```
public void addAge()
        {
        dropAge.Items.Insert(0, "Välj ålder");
        int index = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
            dropAge.Items.Insert(index, li);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Code for getting the users information:

```
private void getData(Guid user)
    {
        var repository = new DAL.Repository.UpdateRepository();
        currentProfilbild.ImageUrl = "~/" + repository.getAvatar(user);
        Fnamn.Text = repository.getName(user);
        Enamn.Text = repository.getEnamn(user);
        tbxPresText.Text = repository.getPresText(user);
        var gender = repository.getGender(user);

        try
        {
            var age = repository.getAge(user).Trim();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
            {
                addAge();

            }
            else 
            {
                dropAge.SelectedValue = repository.getAge(user).Trim();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Linq-code:

```
public string getAge(Guid uID)
    {
        using (var context = new dbEntities())
        {
            var user = context.UserInformation.First(c => c.UserId == uID);
            return user.Ålder;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error could be here:

```
public string getAge(Guid uID)
{
    using (var context = new dbEntities())
    {
        var user = context.UserInformation.First(c => c.UserId == uID);

        if(user != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Ålder))
          return user.Ålder;
        else
          return string.empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the exception is here, since the age is null and you're trying to do a Trim operation.

```
var age = repository.getAge(user).Trim();
```

May be you can do this.

```
var age = repository.getAge(user);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
{
     age = age.Trim();
}
```

BTW, you might considering bringing all the data in one call rather than calling multiple times for firstname, lastname, age, etc.